# How to send configuration from ExpressJS to Aurelia

Tags: express, configuration, aurelia, bootstrapping

I am building a website based on https://github.com/Vheissu/aurelia-starter-node. It will have some backend logic in the /api area and there will be also a SPA area handled by Aurelia. I would like to:

- read config in express app (https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) using `require('config')`
- use this config on the server (usual stuff)
- use a subset of this config on the client (in the Aurelia app)

I know about https://github.com/Vheissu/Aurelia-Configuration but I don't want to maintain two config sets handled by different libraries, dealing with setting the environment in two places etc.

**Question**: is there a clean way to do what I am looking for?

My thoughts so far:

- pass something to aurelia bootstrapping logic, but I can't find any info about this
- ugly solution: rendering the config as global variable into index.html (the one which is the master page for the SPA) and read it from Aurelia code, more less like [How to pass data from ASP.NET WebForms to Aurelia Global Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602231/how-to-pass-data-from-asp-net-webforms-to-aurelia-global-scope)

Comment: In my opinion, your client-side should be independant from server-side. So, you must have 2 config sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up keeping the configuration in the server code and rendering only the client part of it to the body of the page like so:

When defining aurelia routes for my app:

```
let model = {
    clientConfig: {
        x: 123
    }
};
res.render('index.html', model);
```

And then in view (using ejs templates):

```
<script>
    var config = <%- JSON.stringify(clientConfig) %>;
</script>
```

For me this feels much cleaner than maintaining the config in two places.